# Updating a progress bar in an ASP page

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an .aspx page that connects to a remote application. I want to add a progress bar to the web page to show the client, the current progress of the operation. There are many text fields in the page and I do want the content to be displayed to the user all the time. (I do not want the page to be refreshed every time the progress bar updates). Is there any way to only update the progress bar without refreshing the whole page, using C# or JavaScript?

p.s. I am kind of new to JavaScript, so some kind of an explanation is greatly appreciated.

(forgive me if the English used is wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to make use of the AJAX extensions that are enabled in .NET 3.5 by default.

You'll simply put a scriptmanager anywhere on the page, wrap the content that you want to update in an UpdatePanel (which will enable partial page updates) and use an UpdateProgress to feedback the progress to the user.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more.